# Bonding 3 ADSL lines together to achieve higher speeds (UK)

Tags: router, internet-connection, adsl, broadband, bonding

I wonder if I can bond more than one ADSL line to increase the speed. I'm not talking about balancing! I need one connection which needs to be pretty fast (I'm not sure but I think it's on layer 4)

I live in London, however as we know there is spots where fibre is not available and will not be. So my only option is to spend a lot of money on broadband times 3-4.

With that, I could have at least 3 lines connected to my house (my provider let's me do that) and achieve 3-4 times the speed I get currently.

Now, my question is, is this possible after all? If yes, what router should I get for it? (maximum I wanna spend on that router is 100 GBP)

I'm not new to networking, but completely new to ADSL stuff because in my home country we all have FTTP.

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose mobile network is also developed in London and it has less geographical limitation than fibre. I would investigate in that direction, I suppose it won't even be more expensive than 3-4 ADSL lines.

Comment: You would need a router that supports Link Aggregation. This way you bond them together. But keep in mind that it needs to be a 1GB switch.

Comment: I cant edit the last post but I meant *Router.

Comment: Link Aggregation also needs support from the ISP's end - I doubt you'd get something viable for £100 tho; You could build your own PFSense box and use that with CARP or the like for load balancing;

Comment: Thanks for the info, as I said load balancing is not an option because I need this for huge file downloads at about 1TB a month or more. This leads to answer the first answer I reveived, I cannot go on 4G because of mu usage needs. No provider offers unlimited LTE or 3G.

Comment: @user3102196 Yes have a look at; http://www.aa.net.uk/kb-broadband-bonding.html though I'm not sure if it will be in with your price range. You may find that www.zen.co.uk can also do the same but you would have to call them/email. Other providers may offer a bonding service but you need to have a look round.